# CSS: How to refer to a tag

Tags: html, css, tags

I know how to refer to a `tag` with an `id` or `class` in `css`

```
 <table id="cooltable">
      <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

so in `css`, u refer this `<table>` by

```
 table#cooltable{
     ...
 }
```

However, if I want to refer the `<td>` in `<table>` in css, how do I that?

Comment: Please read a book on CSS instead of blindly adopting it and learning it as you code.  You'll be much better off if you understand how it works.  Chances are, upon learning it, you will go back and look at old CSS that you wrote and laugh at yourself.

Comment: The table here gives a nice overview about all the available selector patterns in CSS2: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html and for CSS3: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Comment: This can be answered in a comment: #cooltable td { ... }. However, this will be selecting ALL the td elements that are under #cooltable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In CSS, the space character on its own means "descendant". For example, this refers to every `td` that is a descendant of `table#cooltable`:

```
table#cooltable td {
    ...
}
```

You can also use the `>` operator: this is more strict, and only applies to direct children. To achieve the same effect using this, you would write:

```
table#cooltable > tr > td {
    ...
}
```

In this case, I'd prefer the first option, but there are some situations—multiple layers of `<div>` tags, for example, or nested tables, where this is a very useful tool.

Comment: Note: The child selector doesn't work in IE6. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selector_child.html

Answer (score 3):

```
#cooltable td
```

or

```
#cooltable tr
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table#cooltable td {
    /* css goes here */
}
```